# Asterisk not registering to SIP provider

Tags: asterisk, sip

I have clean Debian VPS that I have installed Asterisk on.
I have a SIP account and number with a VoIP provider. I'm trying to make my asterisk register to that SIP account. However, it always times out. I'm fairly new to asterisk but I think the sip.conf is correct.

I turned on debugging and this is what I get every time

```
---
Retransmitting #7 (no NAT) to 80.244.65.70:5060:
REGISTER sip:sip-gw6.t3.se SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 11.MY.VPS.IP:5060;branch=z9hG4bK72be2ee7
Max-Forwards: 70
From: <sip:USERNAME@sip-gw6.t3.se>;tag=as5ace2218
To: <sip:USERNAME@sip-gw6.t3.se>
Call-ID: 4d010f6f689d1a1420696c025f07cb18@127.0.1.1
CSeq: 103 REGISTER
User-Agent: Asterisk PBX 11.13.1~dfsg-2+b1
Expires: 120
Contact: <sip:provider@11.MY.VPS.IP:5060>
Content-Length: 0


---
REGISTER 10 headers, 0 lines
Reliably Transmitting (no NAT) to 80.244.65.70:5060:
REGISTER sip:sip-gw6.t3.se SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 11.MY.VPS.IP:5060;branch=z9hG4bK71b213aa
Max-Forwards: 70
From: <sip:USERNAME@sip-gw6.t3.se>;tag=as5ace2218
To: <sip:USERNAME@sip-gw6.t3.se>
Call-ID: 4d010f6f689d1a1420696c025f07cb18@127.0.1.1
CSeq: 104 REGISTER
User-Agent: Asterisk PBX 11.13.1~dfsg-2+b1
Expires: 120
Contact: <sip:provider@11.MY.VPS.IP:5060>
Content-Length: 0


---
[Jul 27 05:51:32] NOTICE[588]: chan_sip.c:15071 sip_reg_timeout:    -- Registration for 'USERNAME@sip-gw6.t3.se' timed out, trying again (Attempt #3)
Really destroying SIP dialog '4d010f6f689d1a1420696c025f07cb18@127.0.1.1' Method: REGISTER
Retransmitting #1 (no NAT) to 80.244.65.70:5060:
REGISTER sip:sip-gw6.t3.se SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 11.MY.VPS.IP:5060;branch=z9hG4bK71b213aa
Max-Forwards: 70
From: <sip:USERNAME@sip-gw6.t3.se>;tag=as5ace2218
To: <sip:USERNAME@sip-gw6.t3.se>
Call-ID: 4d010f6f689d1a1420696c025f07cb18@127.0.1.1
CSeq: 104 REGISTER
User-Agent: Asterisk PBX 11.13.1~dfsg-2+b1
Expires: 120
Contact: <sip:provider@11.MY.VPS.IP:5060>
Content-Length: 0
```

This is my **sip.conf**

```
[general]
port=5060
bindaddr=0.0.0.0
qualify=no
disable=all
allow=alaw
allow=ulaw
dtmfmode=rfc2833
srvlookup=yes
register => USERNAME:PASSWORD@sip-gw6.t3.se/provider

[provider]
type=peer
insecure=port,invite
nat=no
canreinvite=no
authuser=USERNAME
defaultuser=USERNAME
fromuser=USERNAME
fromdomain=sip-gw6.t3.se
secret=PASSWORD
host=sip-gw6.t3.se
dtmfmodf=rfc2833
context=provider-in ;extensions.conf context for inbound calls
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
```

I can register fine using Softphone on my PC. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've followed x amount of guides but asterisk never succeeds to register and I'm not sure what could be going wrong. It's timing out but maybe something in the sip.conf isn't configured correctly.

Comment: I would recommend to capture register message when you are using softphone and compare with register message from Asterisk and check what differs.

Comment: ensure that your firewall is configured properly -- I notice you have "nat=no" for the provider.  Since your ip is obfuscated, I can't tell if it is a public IP or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my ITSP was blocking certain IP ranges.
Moved my VPS to a different datacenter, got a different IP range and it started working...

Comment: The reason why they did can be that they know that the IP Range is used for shared hosting with multiple "Servers" sharing the same IP which can be a major problem, so as a result some carriers do block certain ranges. An other reason can be that the service you used is also providing their services to hackers which will run SIP attack/brute force software on it, we have blocked several ranges of providers which regularly show up with attacks on our systems as well.